# Eclipse Codeium Plugin broken?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to install eclipse plugin codeium in eclipse (4.28 and 4.27)

it says "The following solutions are not available: Codeium 0.1.0"

[image: Warning]

Also the page https://exafunction.github.io/codeium-eclipse gives a NOT FOUND error.

On 27 july the plugin is broken for eclipse?

Reference page: https://codeium.com

Comment: Hava you tried starting from the Eclipse marketplace - https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/codeium

Comment: Yes, of course, but it didn´t work.

Comment: The update site `https://exafunction.github.io/codeium-eclipse/` works for me (in a web browser it gives a NOT FOUND, but update site files like [`https://exafunction.github.io/codeium-eclipse/content.jar`](https://exafunction.github.io/codeium-eclipse/content.jar) are found). I get prompted "Proceed with the installation anyways?" only when installing it via Marketplace, not via _Help > Install New Software..._ What happens if you just hit _Yes_ to proceed?

Comment: @howlger What about the license then? For me it says: "Proprietary Software" and "Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, is not permitted in any form or by any means."

Comment: You can use it for free, but you have to create an account: https://codeium.com/eclipse_tutorial Be aware that when you use it, [data is sent from you to Exafunction, which they use to improve their services](https://codeium.com/terms-of-service). You are not allowed to copy their update site `https://exafunction.github.io/codeium-eclipse` and provide it to others.